# How to setup k8s IP's with internal network?

Tags: kubernetes, networking

Recently I decided to set up a k8s cluster on a few VM's.
I worked with K8s in the past but it's a long time since.
One of the things I want to run in the cluster is a web server with Nginx.

I have 3 VM's 1 master, 2 workers. They have each an external and internal IP.

I was wondering how I should set up k8s.
So I would want to use the external IP as my cluster IP but the nodes should communicate with the internal network.

How do I need to configure this?
I guess I need one of these options of the `kubeadm init` command but I am not sure?

```
--control-plane-endpoint
--apiserver-advertise-addres
```

If Someone could explain with an example that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood you correctly, if not please update me.

> So I would want to use the external IP as my cluster IP but the nodes should communicate with the internal network.

First of all your external IP need to be

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
....
type: LoadBalancer
```

> but the nodes should communicate with the internal network

For this purpose, you should use `StaefulSet` instead of deployment.

The main difference from your perspective (in order to answer your question) is the `StatefulSet` attaches a unique FQDN to your pod and this address is guaranteed to be "attached" to the pod when you reschedule it.

So you should have something like this:

- nginx - Exposed via LoadBalancer (external IP)
- apps  - StatefulSet apps that have a unique IP and the Nginx can communicate with them using this IP.

---

[image]

Comment: You almost always need a Service to go with your Pods; the Service [provides a DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and basic load balancing across pods.  This works even with a Deployment.  I'd reserve a StatefulSet for the cases where you specifically need its characteristics (names for specific pods and not the service as a whole; distinct storage per pod; predictable naming).